# DatagridView does not refresh after i have added deleted or inserted new items from its linkcolumns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

What happens is after i perform any one operation the datagridview updates and reflects the operation performed.But i cannot perform any more operation after first operation.Its as if it goes in read only mode or those links stop to work.Am new to datagridviews any help is appreciated.

My code to display the datagridview.

```
public void DisplayDataGridView()
    {

        Con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from reg", Con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        Con.Close();
    }
```

My code to add 3 columns insert delete and edit.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayDataGridView();

        DataGridViewLinkColumn Editlink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
        Editlink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
        Editlink.HeaderText = "Edit";
        Editlink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
        Editlink.Text = "Edit";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Editlink);
     }
```

And finally my delete code.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)//delete
        {
            string id = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value);
            Con.Open();
            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from reg where ID=" + id + "", Con);

            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Con.Close();

            DisplayDataGridView();
            //dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
```

I am only able to perform any one operation and then cannot do anything else.Also after first operation no other operation is reflected in database.

Comment: set a breakpoint to `dataGridView1_CellContentClick` event and see what it's going. I think the problem is this line: `if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)` because it may not have such column.

Comment: It gets deleted. The code for deletion is right. Suppose there are 5 rows and i delete 1 then it shows 4 rows which is correct.How ever if i try to delete one more row nothing happens there nor in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your "delete" code block will not execute because `ColumnIndex` of `EditLink` not 6 anymore

Every time when `DataGridView` updated with new `DataSource`,
all generated columns are removed and new columns will be generated
(if `DataGridView.AutoGenearateColumns = true` - As I assume is in your case)

`EditLink` not removed because wasn't generated by `DataGridView`, it was added manually.
After new `DataSource` are setted `ColumnIndex` of `EditLink` column became 0.

For workaround use column name when you create column in the `Load` event handler

```
Editlink.Name = "columnDelete";
```

Then in the `CellContentClick` event handler compare indexes using name

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["columnDelete"].Index)
{
    //delete code
}
```

I prefer using column names instead of indexes. With names I can be sure I will get column, even after changing order of the columns in `DataGridView`

Comment: So i have to as @Jeremy Thompson said? Put the link code in Displaydatagridview?

Comment: Suggestion of @Jeremy Thompson will work too, but I think comparing to hardcoded `ColumnIndex` not good solution unless your sure it never change. For example you add Column to your database table next week, then `EditColumn` index will be 7. And creating new column every time you need to update data not very effective.

Comment: Aha thanks @Fabio i did not consider what will happen if more columns added. I will try your method today.Thanks a lot for helping me out